NHibernate 2nd Level Cache Contamination with Incorrect Group Data in QueryOver
TLDR
Trying to understand why second level cache stores user as having a single group in the groups collection after calling a method that uses left join.
Overview
I'm encountering an issue with NHibernate's second-level cache when retrieving users and their associated groups.
When I call the GetUsersByDomain method it will return only users associated with a particular domain.
Users are associated to domains through their participation in groups.
When I ask for users associated with a particular domain and do a left join JoinQueryOver for group, it looks like the user group collection is stored with only a single group (the group associated with the domain).
When I as for users associated with a particular domain, but do an inner join, the query will still result in a single user, single group, single domain (good!) but the second level cache will not assume that the groups collection has only one record.
Code
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsersByDomain(bool loadGroups = false, params Guid[] domainIds)
{
    var getUsers = m_GenericRepository.GetSession().QueryOver<User>();

    IQueryOver<User, Group> usersAndGroups = null;

    if (loadGroups)
    {
        usersAndGroups = getUsers.JoinQueryOver<Group>(x => x.Groups, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
    }
    else
    {
        usersAndGroups = getUsers.JoinQueryOver<Group>(x => x.Groups);
    }

    var result = usersAndGroups
        .JoinQueryOver<TestShellDomainGroup>(x => x.TestShellDomainGroups)
        .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Domain.Id).IsIn(domainIds)
        .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity).List<User>();

    return result;
}

Mappings
    public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
    {
        public UserMap()
        {
            Table("UserInfo");
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Increment();
            HasManyToMany(x => x.Groups)
                .Table("UserGroup")
                .ParentKeyColumn("UserInfoId")
                .ChildKeyColumn("GroupId")
                .AsSet().Cache.ReadWrite();
    
            Cache.ReadWrite();
        }
    }
    
    public class GroupMap : ClassMap<Group>
    {
        public GroupMap()
        {
            Table("GroupInfo");
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Increment();
            HasManyToMany(x => x.Users)
                .Table("UserGroup")
                .ParentKeyColumn("GroupId")
                .ChildKeyColumn("UserInfoId")
                .AsSet().Inverse().Cache.ReadWrite();
    
            HasMany(x => x.TestShellDomainGroups)
                .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
                .Inverse()
                .Not.LazyLoad()
                .AsSet()
                .Cache.ReadWrite();
    
            Cache.ReadWrite();
        }
    }

Tests
Please note that 'admin1' has three groups, and one of those groups is associated with LogOnManager.GlobalDomain.DomainId
[TestMethod]
public void GetWrongGroupCount()
{
    var users = Server.UserRepositoryChannel.GetUsersByDomain(true, LogOnManager.GlobalDomain.DomainId);
    var res = Server.AdminGateway.GetUserByName("admin1");
    Assert.IsFalse(res.GroupIds.Length == 1);
}

[TestMethod]
public void GetRightGroupCount()
{
    var res = Server.AdminGateway.GetUserByName("admin1");
    Assert.IsFalse(res.GroupIds.Length == 1);
}


it looks like cause might be:
https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/460

Why cause? It looks like a fix for your issue. Are you using NHibernate 5.2 or higher?

sorry, I meant that the pull might be the fix to the issue causing this

@RomanArtiukhin I think in my case it might not be handled because my case is a three level
entity (E)
child collection (C1)

child collection of child collection (C2)

restriction is on C2.
left join is on C1
so C1 is limited  by trestriction on C2, but will still get cached because it doesnt have a restriction on itself.
